# Access body attributes of node request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I am making HTTP GET requests to an API that returns employee data using the `request` package. The API returns information such as `first_name`, `last_name` etc.

My question is how can access these attributes from the request? Right now I have the following code:

```
request("http://localhost:3000/api/employee", function(err, res, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

This prints the body as a string, not an object so I can't do something like:

```
console.log(body.first_name) //returns 'undefined'
```

Comment: add the whole code !

Comment: The rest of my code is just requiring various modules. I've posted the most relevant parts of my code showing where I am trying to print out various attributes of the data returned in the body.

Comment: @Venkatraman The OP most certainly should not "add the whole code"! Questions should be a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This question is a good example of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to parse that string with `JSON.parse` in order to become a js object:

```
apiResponse = JSON.parse(body)
console.log(apiResponse.first_name)
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below snippet.

```
var request = require("request");

request({
  uri: "http://localhost:3000/api/employee",
  method: "GET"
}, function(error, response, body) {
  console.log( JSON.parse(body) );
});
```